# USB proxy driver or equivalent solution?

Tags: c++, c, usb, driver, kernel

Problem: Mediate USB traffic/data

I would like to accept inbound traffic on a specific USB port and replicate it exactly as outbound traffic on another specific USB port, in effect accomplishing a USB proxy. By extension, then, the connections need to be two-way. An additional requirement is that the port must be able to fake its identity (vendor ID, product ID, ...) as seen by an external device. Should the given solution also be able to dump/log the raw traffic, that would be fantastic, although not a requirement. Target platforms are Windows and/or Linux (any will do).

Before going on an epic journey and writing a custom driver, which is fairly likely to induce brain damage, I would like to ask if anyone has ever done anything similar, or could possibly conceive of the pieces needed to assemble this puzzle. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my work we have used this Beagle USB Analyzer.  It sits between device and host and captures all traffic without interruption.  It works in windows and linux and functions even with USB 2.0 highspeed ports.

http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle_usb480/

Highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is doable out of the box, without extra hardware.

What kind of device can you expect to connect to the "upstream" port of the proxy? Assuming there's a regular device (let's say a mouse, just as an example) on the "downstream" port, the device at upstream needs to be a USB host in order to handle the USB device in a meaningful way.

But you can't connect the USB port of your computer (which already is the host for all its USB root ports) directly to another computer, that's a total violation of USB's network topology. Both ports contain +5 V power rails, and if you connect those together, you're likely in for a shock. And/or a private fireworks display. Or a trip to your nearest motherboard and/or PSU retailer ...

Also, since USB is quite dynamic and so on, I don't think you can expect the bitstream from one port to be meaningful if repeated out another port, since address information etc might change.

There are 100% software USB analyzers, like http://www.usblyzer.com/, but I'm not so sure about proxies like what you describe.

Comment: +1: all the USB ports on a PC are host ports and they can't be connected to other host ports for both electrical and protocol reasons

Comment: would it for example be possible to use some kind of hardware that would act as a non-host port?

Comment: Maybe a USB hub?